# Routage in CodeIgniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing

I have a problem....I removed index.php from url...So ma route is :

```
$route['default_controller'] = "pages/show/index";
$route['photo'] = "pages/show/photo";
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/blogCI/';
```

If I write in browser : localhost/blogCI/photo doesn't work, but if I write localhost/blogCI/index.php/photo it's work...
I have a .htaccess in root:

```
   RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

I use apache and mod rewrite is actived and in my config

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Everything is normal but I don't understand where is the problem...Help me guys please!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I tried that but no results

Comment: how do you define default controller ? what error you are getting ?

Comment: replace `RewriteBase /` with `RewriteBase /blogCI/`

Answer (score 0):

Won't work in a subfolder.

Create virtual host if you need CI to be located in that folder or move it to www root.